# How to deserialize this xml in a c# model

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have this part of xml output

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetProvenienzeWebResponse xmlns:ns1="https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php">
         <return xsi:type="tns:GetProvenienzeWebReturn">
            <error xsi:type="xsd:int">-1</error>
            <message xsi:type="xsd:string">test deserialize</message>
            <provenienze xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType=":[2]">
               <item xsi:type="xsd:">
                  <id xsi:type="xsd:string">1</id>
                  <descrizione xsi:type="xsd:string">webconnector test</descrizione>
                  <lotto xsi:type="xsd:string">5</lotto>
                  <crowdSN xsi:type="xsd:string">N</crowdSN>
               </item>
               <item xsi:type="xsd:">
                  <id xsi:type="xsd:string">9999999</id>
                  <descrizione xsi:type="xsd:string">PROVENIENZA GENERICA</descrizione>
                  <lotto xsi:type="xsd:string">0</lotto>
                  <crowdSN xsi:type="xsd:string">N</crowdSN>
               </item>
            </provenienze>
         </return>
      </ns1:GetProvenienzeWebResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Deserialization produces this error:

> The specified type was not recognized: name='GetProvenienzeWebReturn',
> namespace='https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php',
> at <return xmlns=''>.

This is my classes, generated with Visual Studio's Paste Special:

```
[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{
    public EnvelopeBody Body { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string encodingStyle { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php")]
    public GetProvenienzeWebResponse GetProvenienzeWebResponse { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class GetProvenienzeWebResponse
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public @return @return { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class @return
{
    public byte error { get; set; }
    public object message { get; set; }
    public returnProvenienze provenienze { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class returnProvenienze
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public returnProvenienzeItem[] item { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")]
    public string arrayType { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class returnProvenienzeItem
{
    public uint id { get; set; }
    public string descrizione { get; set; }
    public byte lotto { get; set; }
    public string crowdSN { get; set; }
}
```

I think the problem is due to the XmlType attribute, but after various tests I was unable to modify it so that it could read the contents of the node.

I tried changing the XmlType attribute of @return class as:

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "https://mydonorosrwc.grupposandonato.it/lib_ws/cwsep/v2/Connector.php", TypeName = "GetProvenienzeWebReturn")]
```

But the return object has always the properties with default values (0 for int, null for string and object)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The type is an inherited class so you need [XmlInclude].  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure I understand, could you show me what to change in the model?
I updated the question by inserting full xml and models.